# In Go-Lang how can i take JSON file and quote to css

Tags: json, go

I have sumfile.json that needs to be quoted into specific format.

```
{
  "address": "312312321321",
  "number": "d56"
  "type": "chocolate",
  "model": "dcdas55A",
  "partnumber": "adasdasA",
 
   ...
```

and i have to make it look like this:

```
  "data": "{\"address\": null, \"number\": \"-DI1\", \"_type\": \"\", \"model\": \"CI STO\", \"number\": \"603sjhhd2\",
```

Comment: Just read the file into a byte slice, convert the bytes into a string, and then marshal the string as JSON.

Comment: @mkopriva if you look at my code function quoted string wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: I don't know Tank, I don't know how you got the `marshaledBytes` and what the content of those bytes is, I also don't know the JSON spec inside-out and so I do not know if `strconv.Quote` will output a valid JSON string. What I know however, is that if you pass a string to `json.Marshal`, the output will be a valid JSON string.

Comment: in your desired result you also removed the newlines.   The quote function won't do that, but from what I can tell it should correctly render an arbitrary string as a json string.  I think the unmarshal/marshal is the cleaner approach

Answer (score 2):

Just read the file into a byte slice, convert the bytes into a string, and then marshal the string as JSON.

```golang
f, err := os.Open("sumfile.json")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

raw, err := io.ReadAll(f)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

out, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{"data": string(raw)})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0lCwHLC8Tno